# Is there a way to start windows installer and avoid the UAC popup

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I need to run an *.msi file from within my c# application.  The install runs without a UI and must run unattended.  Is there a way to avoid the UAC popup window?

Comment: If you run your application as administrator, the UAC should not pop-up.

Comment: If there was a general way to avoid the UAC prompt, what would the point of UAC be?

Comment: Is this an upgrade scenario?  Would it be enough to have a UAC prompt during the initial installation but to not have prompts during upgrades?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter: Yes it is an Update/Upgrade scenario.  I do not care about initial setups.  Updates need to be started from within my software without any user interaction.

Comment: Would the person who kindly downvoted my question be please so polite and would justify the reason for the downvote?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I've created solutions that did things like:

1) Install lays down app and a windows service running as SYSTEM.

2) Application checks webservice for new version and downloads to a temp directory.

3) Application informs service that MSI is present in temp directory.

4) Service "blesses" MSI by performing msiexec /jm foo.msi /qn (published/assigned)

5) Service informs application that the MSI is now trusted.

6) Application performs installation of MSI without UAC prompt.  msiexec /i foo.msi /qn RESTARTAPP=1

This pattern requires the MSI to be fully compliant in terms of custom action scheduling / security sandboxing.  It's also advised the application quits as soon as launching the MSI as to get out of the way and to have a custom action conditioned with RESTARTAPP to relaunch the application to give it a seamless user experience.

I've thought about making this a FOSS project/pattern but the security considerations to ensure it's not abused are beyond what I want to deal with.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a an elevation prompt somewhere, but you could defer the UAC prompt to your C# launcher. It starts, gets UAC elevation, and if you then start the MSI install as a CreateProcess() initiation (or just call MsiInstallProduct) the MSI will also be elevated.